# clearing the data and appending the old values in to text box

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to append values in to text box with out clearing the completely.. I will show an example in fiddle about what I am trying to achieve here..

my code looks like

```
$("#newbutton").click(function(){ 
$("#srchBox").val($("#srchBox").val().replace(/\s\S+$/,'').replace(/^\S*$/,'')  + ' ' +"a"+ ":(" +"b" + ") ");
});
```

I have given some sample input in the fiddle, it works fine as expected for the sample input #1, but it doesnt in the case of sample input 2,
http://jsfiddle.net/sztnN/

```
//sample input1 : word map game cool
//output : word map game a:(b)

//sample Input2: word map
//output: a(b)
//ExpectedOutput: word a:(b)
```

Comment: I wanna retain the old values with changing the format of new one as well as Ive shown in the fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
$("#srchBox").val($("#srchBox").val().replace(/\w+[.!?]?$/, '')  + ' ' +"a"+ ":(" +"b" + ") ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sztnN/1/

Comment: you can test in jsfiddle instantly